# Is there a way to move a particular JSON key to the top of the JSON which has been created using the Jackson JsonGenerator?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am creating a JSON using the `Jackson JsonGenerator` approach and everything seems to work perfectly fine apart from a minor glitch. I would like to move the particular key present in the created JSON to the top of the JSON.

I am creating a key `schema` which appears at the bottom of the JSON. I would like to know if there is a way to move it to the top of the JSON after finished creating the JSON.

Following is the JSON that I am creating:

```
public class JacksonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringWriter jsonObjectWriter = new StringWriter();
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(jsonObjectWriter).useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("a", "Value-A");
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("c", "Value-C");
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("b", "Value-B");
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("schema", "2.0");
        jsonGenerator.close();
        jsonGenerator.flush();
        System.out.println(jsonObjectWriter.toString());
    }
}
```

Following is the output I am getting:

```
{
  "a" : "Value-A",
  "c" : "Value-C",
  "b" : "Value-B",
  "schema" : "2.0"
}
```

I would like to convert the JSON something like this:

```
{
  "schema" : "2.0",
  "a" : "Value-A",
  "c" : "Value-C",
  "b" : "Value-B"
}
```

I would like to fetch the `schema` from my created JSON and add it to the top of the JSON.

`Please Note:`

1. I am aware the JSON order does not matter but I am doing this for better readability purposes. If there is a way then it would be really useful for the reader to understand the JSON better.
2. I am aware that I can create the `schema` at first in this code but this is just a sample application that I have provided for ease of understanding. In my real application, I have a `Map` that is populated dynamically throughout the execution and I am adding it at the end of the JSON creation. If I add at the first then I will miss out on a few of the values which are populated after creation so I am adding at the end but I want this to appear at the top of the JSON so trying to move to the top.
3. I want to know if there is a direct way to do it rather than looping over the JSON, as my created JSON in the real application can be pretty large.

I would really appreciate it if there was a way to do it or is there any workaround for this.

Comment: Json is just a representation of some objects. It doesn't know the order itself. If you want it to be ordered you need to make those objects ordered. In your example, you can use an ordered map. (i.e. `LinkedHashMap`)

Comment: @zhh Thanks a lot for your response. Actually, I do not need the JSON to be ordered. All I want to do is move a particular key from the bottom to the top of the JSON by accessing it directly. Other elements can be as it is. I believe `Jackson ObjectMapper` has a property to order all the `keys in JSON` which I do not want to use. I want to move the `last key schema` to the top of the JSON file which has been created.